# Django: mysterious slow request before timing middleware kicks in

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django with Sentry to monitor errors and performance. There's one specific endpoint (this doesn't happen with other endpoints) that seems to stall for a few seconds before actually processing the request.

- It's a very simple endpoint, but it does get called a lot.
- It seems to do nothing for a few seconds and is waiting on the time before Django middleware is even called.
- The actual logic that goes into rendering only takes a few hundred milliseconds: something is happening before the Django middleware that causes this to only happen for this view.

What could this mean? I don't often see the `Django.db.close_old_connections` call and I'm hoping someone might have a clue for what might be causing it when the stall is after that, with another stall in the same place towards the end right before close_old_connections is called again.

[image]